# Dynamically paste Visual Studio styled code in a RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, clipboard, text-styling

I'd like to **dynamically paste Visual Studio styled/formatted code (with the font colors) in a RichTextBox**.

It **only works when I paste the code at Runtime as a user** (using `Ctrl+V` in the RichTextBox) but **not when I use this code** `RichTextBox1.Text = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()`.

**Result when I do it manually :**

[image]

**Result when I do it dynamically :**

[image]

I've tried using `RichTextBox1.Text = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)`, but **it doesn't work too** :

[image]

So, **how can I paste the text dynamically to get the same result as when I paste it manually ?**

PS : The full code I'm using is in the screenshots ;)

Regards, Drarig29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Text property of the RichTextBox control does not do formatting, so try using the Rtf property instead:

```
RichTextBox1.Rtf = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know this property and didn't find it when I was _Googling_...